# Android:SQLite to csv export

Tags: android, sqlite, export-to-csv, opencsv

I am unable to export the SQLite data in to csv file.i am unable to see any LOGCAT also. Necessary permissions are granted in Manifest file. could you check and sharp wit your expertise.

Also opencsv and other supporting files are loaded.
Manifest file.  Attaching with Manifest file,Mainactivity data for your kind review,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.bar.example.myapplication">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".CourseSearchActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScanActivity" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Mainactivity.

```js
btnexport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("OCC", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    File exportDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "");
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
      exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, "coke.csv");
    try {
      file.createNewFile();
      com.bar.example.myapplication.CSVWriter csvWrite = new com.bar.example.myapplication.CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));

      Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DATAALL", null);
      csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
      while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
        //Which column you want to export
        String arrStr[] = {
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("_id")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Material_Barcode")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Material_Number")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Material_Description")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Scanning_Date")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Production_Date")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Expiry_Ratio")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Product_Durablity")),
          curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Qty")),
        };
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
      }
      csvWrite.close();
      curCSV.close();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
      Log.e("ResultActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: you can't see the output of the logcat? Have you a device connected? The top of the logcat tells you what device is connected.

Comment: yes device is connected. logcat is running with many other details but i do not see anything related to csv export

Comment: Hi this code looks to be fine.

Comment: and the project runs fine? You can see project related output in the logcat?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the file in the right spot? `getExternalFilesDir()` is not the root external storage directory. It'll be a subdirectory under that; e.g., `<external-root>/Android/data/com.bar.example.myapplication/`.